# Mpz_powm giving wrong answers when hash is big?

Tags: rsa, gmp, modulo

I'm now in trial and error phase, so I assigning some small numbers to the variables as I know the calculation is correct.

In my encryption function, I got this function;

```
hexValues = 65;
d = 2753;
n = 3233;
mpz_powm(sigfile, hexValues, d, n); //sigfile = hexvalues^d % n = 588
```

The power mod function above give me a value of 588

And in my decryption function

```
sigfile = 588; //this is where i read sigfile value from encryption function
e = 17;
N = 3233;
mpz_powm(answer, sigfile, e, N); //answer = sigfile^e %N
```

And obviously I got 65 because I just apply reverse formula on the numbers.

But the issue here is, if I change hexValues(65) from my encryption to 6555, I will have different results from both of the functions.

Let alone to test it with an actual hash value.

Encryption of 6555 as the hash value will give me 2448 but Decryption gives me 89 instead.

*This is an assignment.

*Yes, the variables are intialized with mpz datatype.

Comment: The value to be encrypted must be *less than* your modulus `n`, since the decryption formula is performed modulo `n`, therefore the result will always be `0 - n-1`.

Comment: @Iridium Yeah figured that out few days ago, thank you very much for the help anyway ! Missed that out in RSA's wiki.